# How to get Scala future output into a separate variables

Tags: multithreading, scala, databricks, future

I am having 4 data bricks notebooks running concurrently using scala futures. Using below code.

```
case class NotebookData(path: String, timeout: Int, parameters: Map[String, String] = Map.empty[String, String])

def parallelNotebooks(notebooks: Seq[NotebookData]): Future[Seq[String]] = {
  import scala.concurrent.{Future, blocking, Await}
  import java.util.concurrent.Executors
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
  import com.databricks.WorkflowException

  val numNotebooksInParallel = 4 
  // If you create too many notebooks in parallel the driver may crash when you submit all of the jobs at once. 
  // This code limits the number of parallel notebooks.
  implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numNotebooksInParallel))
  val ctx = dbutils.notebook.getContext()
  
  Future.sequence(
    notebooks.map { notebook => 
      Future {
        dbutils.notebook.setContext(ctx)
        if (notebook.parameters.nonEmpty)
          dbutils.notebook.run(notebook.path, notebook.timeout, notebook.parameters)
        else
          dbutils.notebook.run(notebook.path, notebook.timeout)
      }
      .recover {
        case NonFatal(e) => s"ERROR: ${e.getMessage}"
      }
    }
  )
}

def parallelNotebook(notebook: NotebookData): Future[String] = {
  import scala.concurrent.{Future, blocking, Await}
  import java.util.concurrent.Executors
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  import com.databricks.WorkflowException

  val ctx = dbutils.notebook.getContext()
  // The simplest interface we can have but doesn't
  // have protection for submitting to many notebooks in parallel at once
  Future {
    dbutils.notebook.setContext(ctx)
    
    if (notebook.parameters.nonEmpty)
      dbutils.notebook.run(notebook.path, notebook.timeout, notebook.parameters)
    else
      dbutils.notebook.run(notebook.path, notebook.timeout)
    
  }
  .recover {
    case NonFatal(e) => s"ERROR: ${e.getMessage}"
  }
}



val notebooks = Seq(
 NotebookData("/notebook1",0,Map("Env" -> test.toString())),
 NotebookData("/notebook2",0,Map("Env" -> test.toString())),
 NotebookData("/notebook3",0,Map("Env" -> test.toString())),
 NotebookData("/notebook4",0,Map("Env" -> test.toString()))

)

val res = parallelNotebooks(notebooks)

Await.result(res, 3600000 seconds) // this is a blocking call.
res.value
```

Here each notebook is returning some value with dbutils.notebook.exit(). I am getting return values like this.

```
parallelNotebooks: (notebooks: Seq[NotebookData])scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[String]]
parallelNotebook: (notebook: NotebookData)scala.concurrent.Future[String]
notebooks: Seq[NotebookData] = List(NotebookData(/notebook1,0,Map(Env -> true)), NotebookData(/notebook2,0,Map(Env -> true)),NotebookData(/notebook3,0,Map(Env -> true)),NotebookData(/notebook4,0,Map(Env -> true)))
res: scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[String]] = Future(Success(List(0, 0,0,0)))
res2: Option[scala.util.Try[Seq[String]]] = Some(Success(List(0, 0,0,0)))
```

**Future(Success(List(0, 0,0,0)) and Some(Success(List(0, 0,0,0))** here 0 are the return values from my notebook.

How can I get this values into separate variables. So that I can use this values in later on my need.

Comment: I'm not quite sure about your question, but do you need something like `Future[Seq[(Notebook -> Int)]]` instead? you can do this in your code: `notebook -> dbutils.notebook.run(...)`, you can also convert it to a Map at the end.

Comment: I just want my return values to be stored in a variable

Comment: What is `parallelNotebook` for? It is never used. And what is `res2`?

Answer (score 1):

```
val value: Seq[String] = Await.result(res, 3600000 seconds)
```

`value` will be a `List` of the `String` results from the `dbutils.notebook.run` calls.